# Convert string to timer, and add 1 minute to the string

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsscanner

If I have a string from key and the string is a timer (12:00) how to add 1 minute to the timer, so the label will show 12:01:

```
NSString string = [subDict objectForKey:@"1"];

NSScanner timeScanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
int hours,minutes;
[timeScanner scanInt:&hours];
[timeScanner scanString:@":" intoString:nil]; 
[timeScanner scanInt:&minutes];
```

Thanks

Comment: Did the NSScanner succeed? If so just do `minutes + 1;` and use `stringWithFormat:`?!

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to **take care of the carry.** As to a simple solution, you don't even need a scanner:

```
NSString *timeStr = @"23:59";

NSArray *comps = [timeStr componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
int h = [comps[0] intValue];
int m = [comps[1] intValue];

h += (m + 1) / 60;
h %= 24;

m = (m + 1) % 60;

NSLog(@"The new time is: %02d:%02d", h, m);
```

Comment: It isnt working when I do:

    NSString* stringtime = [subDict objectForKey:@"1"];

    NSArray *comps = [stringtime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    int h = [comps[0] intValue];
    int m = [comps[1] intValue];
    
    h += (m + 1) / 60;
    h %= 24;
    
    m = (m + 1) % 60;

    //Give it to label
    self.num.text = stringtime;

Comment: @user2310932 `NSString* stringtime = [subDict objectForKey:@"1"]; NSArray *comps = [firstPray componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];` - you are not decomposing the string you are getting. Also, learn some basic debugging. This is getting quite tiring for me.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
 self.mylabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",[[string substringToIndex:2] intValue],[[string substringFromIndex:3] intValue]+1];
```

Comment: @user2310932:try like this.